ServiceStack could not resolve type
I feel like I'm missing something simple, but can't see it...
I've initialized a new ServiceStack app using the x tool, and mixed in AutoQueryCrud, and pointed it at a SQL Server database that has only one table.
It works as expected.  I can see the AutoQuery-generated APIs in the ServiceStack standard UI.
There is no hand-written code whatsover in the ServiceModel project.  Here is the config of the Db and AutoQuery:
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(MyComputedApp.ConfigureDb))]

namespace MyComputedApp;

public class ConfigureDb : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) => builder
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            var connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
                ?? "Server=localhost;Database=test;User Id=test;Password=test;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;";

            var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServer2022Dialect.Provider);
            services.AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => dbFactory);

            services.AddPlugin(new AutoQueryFeature
            {
                MaxLimit = 1000,
                IncludeTotal = true,
                GenerateCrudServices = new GenerateCrudServices
                {
                    DbFactory = dbFactory,
                    AutoRegister = true,
                    //AddDataContractAttributes = false,
                }
            });
            // Enable built-in Database Admin UI at /admin-ui/database
            services.AddPlugin(new AdminDatabaseFeature());
        });
}

I now want to override how some of the fields are handled, by defining the Type of the table in the ServiceModel.Types namespace.  So I used x csharp to generate a dtos.cs file, and copied the base type definition of the table from it, and added it to my project.
Now when I run the project I get a failure to launch, with the following error:

Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: Could not resolve
type 'MetaTablePermission'    at
ServiceStack.GenerateCrudServices.ThrowCouldNotResolveType(String
name) in
/home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Server/GenerateCrudServices.cs:line
319    at
ServiceStack.GenerateCrudServices.CreateOrGetType(ModuleBuilder
dynModule, String typeName, List1 metadataTypes, Dictionary2
existingMetaTypesMap, Dictionary2 generatedTypes) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Server/GenerateCrudServices.cs:line 314    at ServiceStack.GenerateCrudServices.CreateOrGetType(ModuleBuilder dynModule, MetadataType metaType, List1 metadataTypes, Dictionary2 existingMetaTypesMap, Dictionary2 generatedTypes) in
/home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Server/GenerateCrudServices.cs:line
508    at
ServiceStack.GenerateCrudServices.GenerateMissingServices(AutoQueryFeature
feature, HashSet1 requestTypes) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Server/GenerateCrudServices.cs:line 271    at ServiceStack.AutoQueryFeature.AfterConfigure(IServiceCollection services) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Server/AutoQueryFeature.cs:line 201    at ServiceStack.ServiceStackServicesOptions.ConfigurePlugins(IServiceCollection services) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/AppHostBase.Options.cs:line 37    at ServiceStack.NetCoreAppHostExtensions.AddServiceStack(IServiceCollection services, IEnumerable1 serviceAssemblies, Action1 configure) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line 645    at ServiceStack.NetCoreAppHostExtensions.AddServiceStack(IServiceCollection services, Assembly serviceAssembly, Action1 configure) in
/home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line
632    at Program.$(String[] args) in
C:\Development\learning\ss\MyComputedApp\MyComputedApp\Program.cs:line
6

Please advise what I am missing?  Why would this happen?
